# Is it possible to access two models from a single function of a controller in Laravel4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

So I'm trying to insert values into two tables from a single form using Laravel4.
this is my Store() function.Am i doing it right..?
I know i should be using two controllers AddressController.php and PeopleController.php.., but can i use a single controller to insert into two tables using a single form.?

```
    public function store()
    {
        $rules = array(
            'address_id'      => 'required',
            'contact_id' => 'required',
            'prefix'  => 'required',
            'firstname' => 'required',
            'middlename' => 'required',
            'lastname' => 'required',
            'suffix' => 'required',
            'occupation'  => 'required',
            'gender'  => 'required',
            'comment'  => 'required'

        );

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);
        $user= Auth::user();
        if (!empty($user->id))
            $user_id=$user->id;

        // process the login
        /*if ($validator->fails()) {
            return Redirect::to('people/create')
                ->withErrors($validator);
        } else {*/
            // store
            $person = new Person;
            $person->user_id=$user_id;
            $person->address_id      =Input::get('address_id');
            //$person->contact_id      = Input::get('contact_id');
            $person->prefix = Input::get('prefix');
            $person->firstname  =Input::get('firstname');
            $person->middlename    =Input::get('middlename');
            $person->lastname    =Input::get('lastname');
            $person->suffix  =Input::get('suffix');
            $person->occupation  =Input::get('occupation');
            $person->gender     =Input::get('gender');
            $person->comment  =Input::get('comment');
            //$person->user_id =Input::get('user_id');
            $person->save();


            $validator = Validator::make($data = Input::all(), Address::$rules);

            $address->address1 = Input::get('address1');
            $address->address2 = Input::get('address2');
            $address->apt = Input::get('apt');
            $address->city = Input::get('city');
            $address->state = Input::get('state');
            $address->zip = Input::get('zip');
            $address->country = Input::get('country');

            $address->save();

            // redirect
            Session::flash('message', 'Successfully created new Employee!');
            //return Redirect::to('addresses/create');
            return Response::json($person);



    }
```

Comment: Of course you can! The only thing you seem to be missing is a `$address = new Address;` and maybe linking the person and the address together

Comment: @teresko: I tried it.., but still not working..!!

Answer (score 0):

As long as you've defined a relationship between the person and address models, then you can use the person model's [push()](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent) method which is designed to save multiple related models in a single step

Note that if you had `fillable` defined for your models, you could also eliminate a lot of those boilerplate `$person->prefix = Input::get('prefix');` statements from your code as well